# Does "run as administrator" on Windows 10 always use the same access token?

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, uac

I am running Windows 10.

This is the way I understood Windows UAC:

A normal admin user has one access token for his admin account and one access token from which most of the special privileges are removed.
The admin token is only used when the user explicitly confirms, that he/she wants to run an application as administrator.

My question is:

**Does a program that I execute with elevated privileges really always use the same access token?**

I started to doubt that because things I did as an administrator (mapping network drives) did not last after I logged off and on again. 
Might this be because of a mechanism in UAC that somehow prevents my elevated actions to be remembered, like that the access token always changes and therefore can't be recognized after logoff for example.

Comment: Did you check "Reconnect after logon" or supply `/PERSISTENT:YES` for mounting a drive? Aside from the token it would depend on the software that actually utilizes it.

Comment: Yes, I supplied /Persistent:yes

Comment: Maybe consider checking `whoami` to see which ID you have on the elevated prompt. As far as I know the ID should always be the same. This could/would be different from the token but such things are usually not bound by the individual token. Does this always happen for your user? Is it a Domain user?

Comment: Yes it is a domain user. I tested it on a different (virtual) machine with WIndows 7 and ran into the same issue, so I think it is not only a problem with my user/machine. And yes, the ID is the same as expected

Comment: configure this setting: http://superuser.com/a/973650/174557